# Woocommerce pagination is not working on newly created pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, pagination, hook

I decided to create an additional page for Products that are on sale. For that, I've copied my archive-product.php file and create a new template. I've connected this template to my new page and face the problem that pagination does not appear. After a few hours searching in google, I find out that my $woocomerce_loop didn't let me enter the pagination function. How can I fix it?

my Sale page code

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
global $wp_query;
get_header( 'shop' ); 

$outside_opt = get_outside_opt();

$shoplayout = 'fullw';
if(isset($outside_opt['outside_shop_page_layout']) && $outside_opt['outside_shop_page_layout']!=''){
    $shoplayout = $outside_opt['outside_shop_page_layout'];
}

$shopcolclass = 12;
switch($shoplayout) {
    case 'fullw':
        $shopcolclass = 12;
        break;
    default:
        $shopcolclass = 9;
}

$wc_product_style = 1;
if(isset($outside_opt['product_style']) && $outside_opt['product_style'] !=''){
    $wc_product_style = $outside_opt['product_style'];
}

?>
    <!-- breadcrumb start -->
    <?php get_template_part('/inc/bredcrumb/header-page-title'); ?>
    <!-- breadcrumb end -->

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_main_content hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
             * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
             * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_website_data() - 30
             */
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' ,'woocommerce_breadcrumb',20 );
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
        ?>

        <div class="page-section section pt-120 pb-120">

            <div class="container">
                 <!--<div class="row">
                    <!-- Product Filter Toggle -->
                    <!--<div class="col-xs-12">
                        <button class="product-filter-toggle"><?php esc_html_e('filter','outside');?></button>
                    </div>
                </div>-->
                <!-- Product Filter Wrapper -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <?php get_sidebar('filter');?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <?php if( $shoplayout == 'left' ){ get_sidebar('category'); } ?>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 <?php echo 'col-md-'.$shopcolclass; ?>">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <?php
                                    /**
                                     * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook.
                                     *
                                     * @hooked wc_print_notices - 10
                                     * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
                                     * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
                                     */
                                    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' ,'woocommerce_result_count',20 );
                                    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' ,'woocommerce_catalog_ordering',30 );
                                    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <?php $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'product',
                            'posts_per_page' => 12, 
                            'meta_query' => array(
                            'relation' => 'OR',
                                array( // Simple products type
                                'key' => '_sale_price',
                                'value' => 0,
                                'compare' => '>',
                                'type' => 'numeric'
                                ),
                                )
                                );
                        $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                            if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>
                                <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>
                                <?php if ($wc_product_style == 2):?>
                                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                                        <?php
                                            /**
                                             * woocommerce_shop_loop hook.
                                             *
                                             * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
                                             */
                                            do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );
                                        ?>
                                        <?php wc_get_template('inc/wooproduct/productstyletwo.php');?>
                                    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
                                <?php else:?>
                                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                                        <?php
                                            /**
                                             * woocommerce_shop_loop hook.
                                             *
                                             * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
                                             */
                                            do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );
                                        ?>
                                        <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
                                    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
                                <?php endif;?>

                            <?php print_r ($GLOBALS['woocommerce_loop']); woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
                            <?php
                                /**
                                 * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook.
                                 *
                                 * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
                                 */
                                remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' ,'woocommerce_pagination',10 );
                                do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
                            ?>

                        <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

                            <?php
                                /**
                                 * woocommerce_no_products_found hook.
                                 *
                                 * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
                                 */
                                do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
                            ?>

                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><?php
                                woocommerce_pagination();?></div>
                        </div>

                </div>
                <?php if( $shoplayout == 'right' ){ get_sidebar('category'); } ?>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_main_content hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
        ?>
    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_sidebar hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
         */
        //do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
    ?>

<?php get_footer( 'shop' ); ?>
```

When I try to call print_r for a $woocomerce_loop before woocommerce_pagination();
I got next values:
[loop] => 0 [columns] => 4 [name] => [is_shortcode] => [is_paginated] => 1 [is_search] => [is_filtered] => [total] => 0 [total_pages] => 0 [per_page] => 0 [current_page] => 1

Also here is my archive-product.php template that actually works:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page which is a post type archive
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     3.4.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

get_header( 'shop' ); 

$outside_opt = get_outside_opt();

$shoplayout = 'fullw';
if(isset($outside_opt['outside_shop_page_layout']) && $outside_opt['outside_shop_page_layout']!=''){
    $shoplayout = $outside_opt['outside_shop_page_layout'];
}

$shopcolclass = 12;
switch($shoplayout) {
    case 'fullw':
        $shopcolclass = 12;
        break;
    default:
        $shopcolclass = 9;
}

$wc_product_style = 1;
if(isset($outside_opt['product_style']) && $outside_opt['product_style'] !=''){
    $wc_product_style = $outside_opt['product_style'];
}

?>
    <!-- breadcrumb start -->
    <?php get_template_part('/inc/bredcrumb/header-page-title'); ?>
    <!-- breadcrumb end -->

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_main_content hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
             * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
             * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_website_data() - 30
             */
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' ,'woocommerce_breadcrumb',20 );
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
        ?>

        <div class="page-section section pt-120 pb-120">

            <div class="container">
                 <!--<div class="row">
                    <!-- Product Filter Toggle -->
                    <!--<div class="col-xs-12">
                        <button class="product-filter-toggle"><?php esc_html_e('filter','outside');?></button>
                    </div>
                </div>-->
                <!-- Product Filter Wrapper -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <?php get_sidebar('filter');?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <?php if( $shoplayout == 'left' ){ get_sidebar('category'); } ?>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 <?php echo 'col-md-'.$shopcolclass; ?>">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <?php
                                    /**
                                     * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook.
                                     *
                                     * @hooked wc_print_notices - 10
                                     * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
                                     * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
                                     */
                                    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' ,'woocommerce_result_count',20 );
                                    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' ,'woocommerce_catalog_ordering',30 );
                                    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>
                                <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>
                                <?php if ($wc_product_style == 2):?>
                                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                                        <?php
                                            /**
                                             * woocommerce_shop_loop hook.
                                             *
                                             * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
                                             */
                                            do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );
                                        ?>
                                        <?php wc_get_template('inc/wooproduct/productstyletwo.php');?>
                                    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
                                <?php else:?>
                                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                                        <?php
                                            /**
                                             * woocommerce_shop_loop hook.
                                             *
                                             * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
                                             */
                                            do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );
                                        ?>
                                        <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
                                    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
                                <?php endif;?>
                            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
                            <?php
                                /**
                                 * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook.
                                 *
                                 * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
                                 */
                                remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' ,'woocommerce_pagination',10 );
                                do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
                            ?>

                        <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

                            <?php
                                /**
                                 * woocommerce_no_products_found hook.
                                 *
                                 * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
                                 */
                                do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
                            ?>

                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><?php woocommerce_pagination();?></div>
                        </div>

                </div>
                <?php if( $shoplayout == 'right' ){ get_sidebar('category'); } ?>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_main_content hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
        ?>
    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_sidebar hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
         */
        //do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
    ?>

<?php get_footer( 'shop' ); ?>
```